# how to convert java enums in c#

Tags: c#, java

I have searched and found many example but still I need expert help.
Below in the code in java:

```
public class myClass {

    public static enum myEnum {
    P("aco", 1000, 4, 8), L("acs", 2100,
            1, 9), S("acn", 3500, 1, 6), H("ach", 5400, 1, 6);

    final public String cc;
    final int bt;
    final int Qp;
    final int lp;

    private myEnum(String cc, int bt, int Qp, int lp) {
        this.cc = cc;
        this.bt = bt;
        this.Qp = Qp;
        this.lp = lp;
    }
};}
```

I have tried to convert it like below by seeing examples:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System;

[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class EnumAttr : System.Attribute
{
    public EnumAttr()
    {
    }     
}

public static class EnumExtension
{
    public static EnumAttr GetAttr(this Enum value)
    {
        Type type = value.GetType();
        FieldInfo fieldInfo = type.GetField(value.ToString());
        var atts = (EnumAttr[])fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EnumAttr), false);
        return atts.Length > 0 ? atts[0] : null;
    }
}

public class myEnumAttr : EnumAttr
{
    public string Desc { get; set; }
} 

public class myClass
{
    public enum myEnum
    {
        [myEnumAttr("aco", 1000, 4, 8)]P, 
        [myEnumAttr("acs", 2100, 1, 9)]L,
        [myEnumAttr("acn", 3500, 1, 6)]S, 
        [myEnumAttr("ach", 5400, 1, 6)]H,

    public String cc;
    int bt;
    int Qp;
    int lp;

    private void myEnum(String cc, int bt, int Qp, int lp) {
        this.cc = cc;
        this.bt = bt;
        this.Qp = Qp;
        this.lp = lp;
    }
};}
```

The above code is not correct as per compiler which I know but how to make it working. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a working version of your approach:

```
// use like
string desc = myEnum.P.GetAttr().Desc;

[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class EnumAttr : System.Attribute
{
    public EnumAttr()
    {
    }     
}

public static class EnumExtension
{
    public static EnumAttr GetAttr(this Enum value)
    {
        Type type = value.GetType();
        FieldInfo fieldInfo = type.GetField(value.ToString());
        var atts = (EnumAttr[])fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EnumAttr), false);
        return atts.Length > 0 ? atts[0] : null;
    }
    public static myEnumAttr GetAttr(this myEnum value)
    {
        Type type = value.GetType();
        FieldInfo fieldInfo = type.GetField(value.ToString());
        var atts = (myEnumAttr[])fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(myEnumAttr), false);
        return atts.Length > 0 ? atts[0] : null;
    }
}

public class myEnumAttr : EnumAttr
{
    public string Desc { get; set; }

    int bt;
    int Qp;
    int lp;

    public myEnumAttr(String desc, int bt, int Qp, int lp) {
        this.Desc = desc;
        this.bt = bt;
        this.Qp = Qp;
        this.lp = lp;
    }
} 

public enum myEnum
{
    [myEnumAttr("aco", 1000, 4, 8)]P, 
    [myEnumAttr("acs", 2100, 1, 9)]L,
    [myEnumAttr("acn", 3500, 1, 6)]S, 
    [myEnumAttr("ach", 5400, 1, 6)]H,
}
```

However, I'm not sure this is the best way to approach this problem. Maybe it'd make more sense to use instances of a class with a `private` constructor.

```
// use like
string desc = MyEnumLike.P.Desc;

public sealed class MyEnumLike
{
    public static readonly MyEnumLike P = new MyEnumLike("aco", 1000, 4, 8);
    public static readonly MyEnumLike L = new MyEnumLike("acs", 2100, 1, 9);
    public static readonly MyEnumLike S = new MyEnumLike("acn", 3500, 1, 6);
    public static readonly MyEnumLike H = new MyEnumLike("ach", 5400, 1, 6);

    public string Desc { get; set; }

    int bt;
    int Qp;
    int lp;

    private MyEnumLike(String desc, int bt, int Qp, int lp) {
        this.Desc = desc;
        this.bt = bt;
        this.Qp = Qp;
        this.lp = lp;
    }
}
```